# sql/php return the count of how many time field have the same id

Tags: php, sql, count

I am looking to create a query which will return the count of how many time fields have the same id. For my case it will be when objects are found in the same bag.

For example see this table:

```
Bagid | Object 
--------------
B1    | wallet
B1    | perfume
B1    | charger
B2    | wallet
B2    | perfume
B2    | pen
B3    | book 
B3    | pen
B3    | wallet
```

So for instance if I was looking for how many time 'wallet' and 'perfume' have been found in the same bag the expected result would be:

`wallet, perfume = 2`

because they appear twice in the same bag.

And afterwards I would like to be able to this for n number of objects which will be stored in an array(but after).

Help would be appreciated, thanks.

---

New Question:

How can I put the objects which should be in IN(), by using a 2d array which contains objects. for example I did ...IN ('$Objects[1][0]', '$Object[1][1]') and it is not working. Objects[1][0] & Object[1][1] are giving me the right object when I echo them. cant find a way to get it to work.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (
  SELECT Bagid
  FROM yourtable
  WHERE Object IN ('wallet', 'perfume')
  GROUP BY Bagid
  HAVING Count(DISTINCT Object)=2
) s
```

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/31326/2).

To support any number of objects, you have to dinamically create the query above, updating the IN clause and the number of objects, or could use a little trick like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (
  SELECT Bagid
  FROM yourtable
  WHERE FIND_IN_SET(Object, 'wallet,perfume')
  GROUP BY Bagid
  HAVING Count(DISTINCT Object)=
    LENGTH('wallet,perfume')-
    LENGTH(REPLACE('wallet,perfume', ',', ''))+1
) s;
```

See it [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/31326/7).

Comment: what about `(pen,wallet)` which are common in `B2 & B3`?

Comment: @DoSparKot yes it could have been 2 as well for (pen,wallet), it was just an example

Comment: @fthiella actually why are you defining the count? I would like it to return the count without having to say 'HAVING Count(*)=2' if possible

Comment: @StringerB HAVING Count(*)=2 is the number of objects you want to match, for example if you need to match wallet, perfume and charger you have to use HAVING Count(*)=3, or you can use my second query, please see this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/31326/24

Comment: @fthiella ok makes sense, thanks. And also why do group it? because if i don't group it it does not return the same count

Comment: @StringerB we need to use a GROUP BY because the values we need to match are on different rows. We select the rows where object is either wallet or perfume, then we group by Bagid and we count the number of times there's a distinct match with HAVING Count(DISTINCT Object)

Comment: @StringerB you could use this query to see how the group by works: SELECT Bagid, Count(DISTINCT Object) FROM yourtable WHERE Object IN ('wallet', 'perfume') GROUP BY Bagid

Comment: @fthiella ok thanks for the clear explanations. How can I put the objects which should be in IN(),  by using a 2d array which contains objects. for example I did ...IN  ('$Objects[1][0]', '$Object[1][1]') and it is not working. Objects[1][0] & Object[1][1] are giving me the right object when I echo them. cant find a way to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  b1.Bagid
FROM 
    bags as b1
JOIN
    bags b2
ON
    b1.Bagid=b2.Bagid
    AND b2.Object='perfume' 
WHERE
    b1.Object = 'wallet'
```

Having an index like `KEY idx1(Object,Bagid)` gives me a reasonable `Using where; Using index` and no warning on MySQL's [EXPLAIN EXTENDED](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain-extended.html).